# Elixir - Check if string is empty

Tags: websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am playing with `Elixir` and `Phoenix Framework` for the first time after following this [Tutorial](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/channels.html)..

I have a simple client/server app.

chat/lib/chat_web/room_channel.ex:

```
defmodule ChatWeb.RoomChannel do
  use Phoenix.Channel

  def join("room:lobby", _message, socket) do
    {:ok, socket}
  end
  def join("room:" <> _private_room_id, _params, _socket) do
    {:error, %{reason: "unauthorized"}}
  end

  def handle_in("new_msg", %{"body" => body}, socket) do
    broadcast! socket, "new_msg", %{body: body}
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
end
```

I want to block empty incoming messages (`body` is empty string)

```
def handle_in("new_msg", %{"body" => body}, socket) do
  # I guess the code should be here..
  broadcast! socket, "new_msg", %{body: body}
  {:noreply, socket}
end
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to block empty incoming messages (body is empty string)

You can add a guard clause for this. Either `when body != ""` or `when byte_size(body) > 0`

```
def handle_in("new_msg", %{"body" => body}, socket) when body != "" do
  ...
end
```

Now this function will only match if `body` is not `""`.

If you also want to handle empty body case, you can add two clauses like this (no need for the guard clause anymore since the second clause will never match if body is empty):

```
def handle_in("new_msg", %{"body" => ""}, socket) do
  # broadcast error here
end
def handle_in("new_msg", %{"body" => body}, socket) do
  # broadcast normal here
end
```

Comment: Does it possible to return some kind of error instead of ignoring those messages?

Comment: Yep, you can add another clause for `"body" => ""`. I've edited my answer to include that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use answer proposed by @Dogbert, but to be 100% sure that string is not empty you can use wrap the `broadcast!` in the helper private function or just wrap into `if` or `unless` (negative if) expression.

```
unless String.trim(body) == "" do
  broadcast! socket, "new_msg", %{body: body}
end
```

If you want to return an error message you try to use something more complex eg.:

```
if String.trim(body) != "" do
  broadcast! socket, "new_msg", %{body: body}
else
  broadcast! socket, "error_msg", %{body: "Body is empty"}
end
```

Comment: Thank you! @Dogbert solutions is so simple... so I'm still not sure yet if I actually need to return error messages or just ignore those messages, but originally I was actually looking for something like your solution.. Too bad I can't accept both answers as both are great!

Comment: You have to consider that a body can be multiple white blank spaces like  "      ". That should also be considered blank/empty no?. I suggest @PatNowak for this reason.